# Unable to write the class name for an audio file in the library in Adobe Anime

Tags: actionscript-3

I have imported audio files to the library with the extension mp3 or wav in adobe anime and then click on one of the files on the right mouse button and choose properties, then a window appears, i choose from action script script for the audio file, what is the reason for not activating everything in this window?

I want to link a button to an audio file in the library in Adobe Anime

[image]

Comment: You need to check "Export for ActionScript" checkbox in order to make that audio object available as a subclass of **Sound** class.

Comment: Here is the problem, the window containing Export for ActionScript is not active and I cannot specify options in it or type the name of the class

Comment: Similar problem here: https://community.adobe.com/t5/animate/linkage-sound-to-actionscript-in-flash-cc/td-p/6102942?page=1

Comment: I installed Adobe Flash CS6 Professionals and found that writing the class name for audio files in the library works fine, unlike Adobe Animate which doesn't work with this feature. Thank you very much for helping us solve the problems we face in as3

Comment: @Mohammedlasharaby make sure in Animate you select to create a new ActionScript (SWF) project and **not** a new HTML5 Canvas project. You cannot add class names to a JS/HTML project.